# How to install addition package with extra data file download

Tags: package-management, software-installation, flash

[image]

Hi I have install flash package along with other packages on Synaptic Package Manager. After apply, I run the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

to install those packages. Then this notification appears. **When I click into the box**  `run this action now`  **it appear the box for my password and it immediatelly disappear**. I have try several times but it still happen.

Here the box when I click `run this action now`.

[image]

I have installed flashplugin package via Synaptic package manager, but there was a update information box which I cannot close. I closed it temporarily and then it reappeared the next day when I start the computer.

[image]

As I checked the syslog file in `/var`. Here are the results when I clicked the `run this action now` button :

```
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy dbus-daemon[1475]: [session uid=1000 pid=1475] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.95' (uid=1000 pid=4035 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real -- pkexec /usr/lib/up" label="unconfined")
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Created slice apps.slice.
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy dbus-daemon[1475]: [session uid=1000 pid=1475] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Started VTE child process 4049 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4038.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: vte-spawn-b702640c-f872-4180-aa93-6cbeca1280e9.scope: Succeeded.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: is your computer behind a proxy?

Comment: @turbulence I use VirtualBox on Window 10. Since I am new to Linux, I just want to run on Virtual Machine.

Comment: Can you try installing this package via the console as root? `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: @MatzZze Yes it works :') . But I am just wondering what is the problem with my previous problem even when I type my password in, it still not work. I have checkout this similar issue but same it seem not helpful at all : https://www.maketecheasier.com/fixing-authentication-issue-dropbox-ubuntu/

Comment: Were you able to install this package without any additional input during install like confirm apt-listchanges or accepting something like a EULA? Something like this sometimes causes such behavior.

Comment: @MatzZze yes when I installed ubuntu-restricted-extra I have accepted the EULA for the products. So it maybe the main cause for my issue ya :") . But do you know how to fix it =)) Or just leave it there, and try install as root through console for latter usage :v

Comment: I'm sorry I meant during the installation process of the flashplugin installer ;)

Comment: @MatzZze So no. After I apply all marked packages on Synaptic , I ran command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`. All other package are installed normally except this flash one. And I did not see any EULA either.

Comment: Hm then maybe `/var/log/syslog` can provide error messages maybe for the time you had that issue